# Passing an Array to Jade/Pug Route in Express

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function, express

I'm new to express and pug so forgive me if this is a noob question but how do I pass the array I created in one function to the route that will render the pug template. I ultimately want to loop though the array and render it as a table.

My code - first I create the array from the data received from a file with the lodash map method. *EDIT - added full code structure -

```
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
   console.log('Error: ' + err);
   return;
   }

  var data = JSON.parse(data);

  var newEventList = data.events.map(events => ({
   id: events.id ,
   name: events.name ,
   venue: events.place.name ,
   address: events.place.location.street + " " + 
   events.place.location.city + " " + events.place.location.zip ,
   coverPicture: events.coverPicture ,
   description: events.description ,
   startTime: events.startTime ,
   endTime: events.endTime
   }));
 });
```

So now I have an array of objects called newEventList.

My route for pug is

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, newEventList) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!', 
     newEventList 
 })
})
```

I added title and message to test my pug template.
in my Pug Template I have

```
h1= message
p= newEventList
```

but in the paragraph that is rendered I get a long error message -

```
function next(err) { // signal to exit route if (err && err === 'route') { return done(); } // signal to exit router if (err && err === 'router') { return done(err) } var layer = stack[idx++]; if (!layer) { return done(err); } if (layer.method && layer.method !== method) { return next(err); } if (err) { layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next); } else { layer.handle_request(req, res, next); } }
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your route definition's callback, remove or rename `newEventList` as your third param.

In your example, `newEventList` is getting assigned to the `done/next` callback. Hence you're seeing a function being printed in your paragraph.

```
var newEventList = // Whatever value;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!', 
    newEventList 
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you but I didn't mention that the data.events.map function is inside another function, so on realisation I think I also have a variable scope issue. So in that function I think I have to return the newEventsList array to make it available to other functions below, apologies I think I may need to re-write the question. I will edit the code to reflect this...

Comment: This did answer my original question, so will accept it. Thanks